# Iteration of a function related to the minimal polynomial of a matrix

Tags: matrices, polynomials

Let $M$ be a singular $n \times n$ matrix over some field. In order to find a matrix $N$ s.t. $MN=0$, I do the following : $p(x)=$ minimal polynomial of $M$. Then the constant term of p is zero (because it equals the determinant of $M$), so $p(x)=q(x)x$ . if we take $N=q(M)$ then by the  Cayley-Hamilton theorem $NM=q(M)M=p(M)=0$.
By pure curiosity I wondered if I did the same thing for $N$, would I recover $M$? in other words: If $r$ is the minimal polynomial of $N$ is there any relationship of $r/x(N)$ and $M$?  Not at all. Instead I always get that $r$ is of the second degree. In order to try to prove this is always the case I thought that it would be enough to replace $M$ with its Jordan normal form $M_J=J^{-1}MJ$, this would lead to the same $p$ and the same $q$, with as result $N_J=J^{-1}MJ$. So let $M$ be a Jordan matrix with (not necessarily different) eigenvalues $0, \lambda_1,\lambda_2, \ldots$. Then $p(x)=x(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)\ldots$ so that $N=(M-\lambda_1)(M-\lambda_2)\ldots$. Why is there an $a$ s.t. $N^2+aN=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $q(x)-q(0)$ is divisible by $x$, the polynomial $(q(x)-q(0))q(x)$ is divisible by $xq(x)=p(x)$. Hence $(q(M)-q(0))q(M)=0$, i e $(N-q(0))N=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality I consider $M$ to be a Jordan matrix. We look closer to the product $N=(M-\lambda_1)(M-\lambda_2)\ldots$. Each of the factors $M-\lambda_i$ has a zero  on the diagonal where a $\lambda_i$ was present. On the other hand everywhere where there was a zero present a $-\lambda_i$ pops up. Making the product we see that everywhere where the $\lambda_i$ were there is now a zero and where there were zeroes there is now only one number $\pm\det(M)$. For the elements not on the diagonal they disappear because there are as many factors $M-\lambda_i$ as the multiplicity of $\lambda_i$. But this is just the size of the corresponding Jordan block. Now we know the structure of the matrix $N$ we can conclude that it represents a projection combined with a scaling. Indeed we have that $(N/q(0))^2=N/q(0)$ which explains that the minimal polynomial of $N$ is of the second degree.